# Visual Missing in Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have recently started to learn about Power-BI and have installed Power BI Desktop on Windows 7 x64 vmware-machine. I have installed .NET Framework 4.5.2 and IE 9 on the machine

I am able to load data and manipulate the data but the report visualization doesn't works at all. No matter what data I connect to, it just doesn't works
I have tried below methods. See below image. None of the charts/maps are working.

1. Reinstall Power BI Desktop
2. Install newer & latest version of Power-BI
3. Restart virtual machine

Please advise!!!

[image: Please see the attached image]

Comment: Troubleshooting 101: What does the "See details" message reveal?

Comment: @teylyn It reads as "Sent a clown face".. meaning sent a email to Microsoft

Comment: Surely that is "frown" not "clown". Do that, then. Send it to Microsoft. They are very good at responding.

Comment: What's the data type of your `sales` column (or measure)? (Modelling tab)

Comment: Did you add any values to the fields ...cant see anything that is being added on the pane in the right